# How to find out if a Facebook ID belongs to a page or a profile?

Tags: python, facebook

When accessing facebook, here are two types of pages you can land on that have the link format *https://facebook.com/identification*.

The first type is a PROFILE, which belongs to a person, and looks somewhat like this: *https://www.facebook.com/zuck*.

The second type are PAGES, that are indistinguishable from profiles by solely looking at the link. Example: *https://www.facebook.com/CardsAgainstHumanity/*

Each of these has a specific ID, which can be easily verified in a website such as *https://findmyfbid.com*. For example, Cards Against Humanity's code is 221295600695. Zuckerberg's code is 4.

My question is: **Is there a way I can distinguish a profile link from a page link without the need to load the page and analyze the elements that show up**? Is anyone aware of ranges of IDs that could help on this distinction? I need to carry this procedure for many links, but using an individual pageload method makes it too resource-consuming.

Thank you :)

Comment: _“I need to carry this procedure for many links”_ - sounds rather shady … what exactly do you need this for? // There are no id ranges or anything like that. I guess you could make an API call for these usernames; for a profile that will get you an error message, whereas for a page it will either return the basic data of the page, or a different error message, that your app is not reviewed for Page Public Content Access.

Comment: 1. I need to perform a check if a valid facebook profile was inputed in one of my fields. My goal is to avoid people inputing 'pages' as profiles.
2. That is a good suggestion! I might try something following this strategy.

Comment: Is this the user’s own profile URL? Then you should rather not have them input it manually to begin with, but have them login to your app, so that you can get a link to their profile via API.

Comment: This strategy works, but the system was developed in a weird way in the past. I already have an extensive list of links which I need to verify. Going through the list of currently reported links, there are three types of links:
1 - Valid profiles
2 - Pages
3 - Invalid Links. My goal is to get rid of the last two.

Comment: Is it all URLs with a username, or do you have some that use the numeric id? If the former, then I would make API requests & check the result - [`/zuck`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=zuck) would get you an error _“(#803) Cannot query users by their username (zuck)”_, whereas [`/CardsAgainstHumanity`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=CardsAgainstHumanity) would either give you basic page data (name and id), if your app had the Page Public Content Access feature approved, or just an error saying that’s missing otherwise.